# Rate Yo! - click add disabled

Tags: jquery, html, rateyo

I have a problem with Rate Yo!

When the user clicks on the stars, the rating is added.

After clicking I would like to add an attribute to id="**rateYo**" (**data-rateyo-read-only** = "**true**"): http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/#option-readonly - which blocks the possibility of voting again.

My code is:

```
$ ("#rateYo").click (function () {
    $ ('#rateYo').attr('data-rateyo-read-only','true');
});
```

Comment: why do you have spaces in `$ ('# rateYo')`?

Comment: Google Translate add white space  - sorry.

Comment: i don't get it. what's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need of manully adding disable attribute.Use `onSet` event - when user give rating make it readonly through `rateYo("option", "readOnly", true);`

```
$("#rateYo").rateYo({
    onSet: function (e, data) {
       alert("The rating is set to " + data.rating() + "!");
       $(this).rateYo("option", "readOnly", true);  // make readonly
    },
    starWidth: "24px"
});
```

You can also do like this if you have already initialized it

```
$("#rateYo").rateYo('option', 'readOnly', true); // disable (make readonly)

$("#rateYo").rateYo('option', 'readOnly', false); // enable
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mogxa8rd/